# Use a function declaration to bind a function to a name

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-plugin, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I am new to flutter. I was using the camera plugin to add the camera to my app. And I got this warning Use a function declaration to bind a function to a name. How can I solve this one?

Code -

```
Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
    final List<Widget> toggles = <Widget>[];

    final onChanged = (CameraDescription? description) {
      if (description == null) {
        return;
      }

      onNewCameraSelected(description);
    };
```

Comment: I believe the warning comes from this line `final onChanged = (CameraDescription? description) {`, which should be `onChanged(CameraDescription? description) {`, here is the specific rule https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_function_declarations_over_variables.html

Answer (score 12):

Dart's effective usage documentation suggests it is a better practice to use function declaration construct than it is to use assignment to an anonymous function.

That is

```
int foo() =>  1
```

instead of

```
int Function() foo = () => 1
```

In your example, that would mean declaring a function onChanged, instead of performing an assignment to onChanged:

```
void onChanged(CameraDescription? description){
  ...body
}
```

The reason you're seeing this warning is that [since Flutter 2.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) flutter_lints is by default packaged along with any flutter applications.

For more on Dart lints and effective usage, see the documentation on [Effective Dart: Usage](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage) and [List of Dart lints](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/index.html). Specifically, the warning you see is found on [prefer_function_declarations_over_variables](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_function_declarations_over_variables.html)