# Dart: How to declarare a top level function that complies with a typedef without warnings?

Tags: flutter, dart

> [I know about this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824256/use-a-function-declaration-to-bind-a-function-to-a-name). It's not a duplicate because it doesn't mention `typedefs`

I have this `typedef`:

```
typedef Prefetcher = Future<void> Function(
    MarkdocNode node, PrefetchContext context);
```

Now I'm trying to define top level functions that comply with the `Prefetcher` signature.

but when I do this:

```
final Prefetcher prefetchTranslatedSentences = (node, context) async {};
```

I'm getting this warning:

> info: Use a function declaration to bind a function to a name. (prefer_function_declarations_over_variables at [anglio_mobile] lib/components/markdown/prefetchers/translated_sentence_prefetcher.dart:3)

I understand that Dart wants me to NOT assign a function to a variable, but rather create a function directly like

```
prefetchTranslatedSentences(node, context) async {}
```

but the problem of the above is that there is no guarantee that `prefetchTranslatedSentences` will comply with the `typedef`

How do I create top-level functions that comply with `typedefs` without getting this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can directly define a function with an inherent guarantee that it conforms to a `typedef`.  However, if your function implementation doesn't match, you'd probably find out pretty quickly from a compilation error somewhere else anyway.  And if you don't, then you can adjust your code to ensure that it does generate such an error:

- Add a test that attempts to use your function with the `typedef`.  If the `typedef` and your function are part of some public API, you probably should have a test for them anyway.  At a minimum:

  ```dart
  void main() {
    Prefetcher _ = prefetchTranslatedSentences;
  }
  ```
- Add a level of indirection:

  ```dart
  Future<void> _prefetchTranslatedSentences(
    MarkdocNode node,
    PrefetchContext context,
  ) async {
    // ...
  }

  final Prefetcher prefetchTranslatedSentences = _prefetchTranslatedSentences;
  ```
- Or just ignore the lint with `// ignore: prefer_function_declarations_over_variables`.

Comment: Thanks for listing the options :). In fact, in TypeScript, my main language, you also can't do what I asked for. But it didn't trigger me because the major linters won't complain. Thanks again!